# bash grep regex how to not grep timestamp

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

I have a file I am trying to retrieve lines that match a particular pattern, and that pattern is `[NUMBERS:NUMBERS:NUMBERS]`

The command I am using here: `cat example.txt | grep -v "\[[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+\]"`
All this seems to do is grep for timestamps even though I specified starting ending literal characters.

Not sure why its not working?

Example data:

```
Jun 22 23:15:09 192.168.0.1 snort[8791]: [120:28:1] (http_inspect) INVALID CHUNK SIZE OR CHUNK SIZE FOLLOWED BY JUNK CHARACTERS [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 192.168.0.6:40932 -> 192.168.0.99:80
Jun 22 23:35:46 192.168.0.1 snort[8791]: [120:28:1] (http_inspect) INVALID CHUNK SIZE OR CHUNK SIZE FOLLOWED BY JUNK CHARACTERS [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 192.168.0.6:37647 -> 192.168.0.18:80
Jun 25 00:17:41 192.168.0.1 snort[8791]: [120:28:1] (http_inspect) INVALID CHUNK SIZE OR CHUNK SIZE FOLLOWED BY JUNK CHARACTERS [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 192.168.0.6:46210 -> 192.168.0.9:80
Jun 25 00:26:30 192.168.0.1 snort[8791]: [120:28:1] (http_inspect) INVALID CHUNK SIZE OR CHUNK SIZE FOLLOWED BY JUNK CHARACTERS [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 192.168.0.6:39421 -> 192.168.0.13:80
Jul 31 16:11:52 192.168.0.1 pkg-static: snort reinstalled: 2.9.16 -> 2.9.16
Jul 31 16:11:53 192.168.0.1 snort[89490]: *** Caught Term-Signal
Jul 31 16:11:58 192.168.0.1 snort[90728]: *** Caught Term-Signal
Jul 31 16:12:13 192.168.0.1 php: /etc/rc.packages: Beginning package installation for snort .
Jul 31 16:12:31 192.168.0.1 php: /etc/rc.packages: [Snort] There is a new set of Snort Subscriber rules posted. Downloading snortrules-snapshot-29160.tar.gz...
Jul 31 16:12:36 192.168.0.1 php: /etc/rc.packages: [Snort] There is a new set of Snort OpenAppID detectors posted. Downloading snort-openappid.tar.gz...
Jul 31 16:13:17 192.168.0.1 php: /etc/rc.packages: Successfully installed package: snort.
Jul 31 16:13:17 192.168.0.1 pkg-static: pfSense-pkg-snort upgraded: 3.2.9.13 -> 3.2.9.14_1
Aug  2 10:47:36 192.168.0.1 php-fpm[76321]: /snort/snort_alerts.php: [Snort] Snort RELOAD CONFIG for LAN...
Aug  2 10:47:36 192.168.0.1 php-fpm[76321]: /snort/snort_alerts.php: [Snort] Snort RELOAD CONFIG for LAN...
Aug  2 10:47:36 192.168.0.1 snort[92683]: Snort Reload: Any change to any output configurations requires a restart.
Aug  2 10:47:59 192.168.0.1 php-fpm[3795]: /snort/snort_alerts.php: [Snort] Snort RELOAD CONFIG for LAN...
Aug  2 10:47:59 192.168.0.1 php-fpm[3795]: /snort/snort_alerts.php: [Snort] Snort RELOAD CONFIG for LAN...
Aug  2 15:41:03 192.168.0.1 snort[92683]: [1:2025701:2] ET POLICY SMB2 NT Create AndX Request For an Executable File [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 192.168.0.2:51231 -> 192.168.0.3:445
Aug  3 11:00:08 192.168.0.1 snort[92683]: [1:2030215:2] ET POLICY DNS Query to .onion proxy Domain (onion . ly) [Classification: Potential Corporate Privacy Violation] [Priority: 1] {UDP} 192.168.0.2:62288 -> 192.168.0.1:53
Aug  3 11:00:08 192.168.0.1 snort[92683]: [1:2030215:2] ET POLICY DNS Query to .onion proxy Domain (onion . ly) [Classification: Potential Corporate Privacy Violation] [Priority: 1] {UDP} 192.168.0.2:62288 -> 192.168.0.1:53
Aug  3 11:00:10 192.168.0.1 snort[92683]: [1:2030216:2] ET POLICY .onion.ly Proxy domain in SNI [Classification: Potential Corporate Privacy Violation] [Priority: 1] {TCP} 192.168.0.2:3698 -> 191.168.0.18:443
Aug  3 13:50:24 192.168.0.1 snort[92683]: [1:2025701:2] ET POLICY SMB2 NT Create AndX Request For an Executable File [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 192.168.0.2:2746 -> 192.168.0.3:445
Aug  3 13:50:24 192.168.0.1 snort[92683]: [1:2025701:2] ET POLICY SMB2 NT Create AndX Request For an Executable File [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 192.168.0.2:2746 -> 192.168.0.3:445
Aug  3 13:50:25 192.168.0.1 snort[92683]: [1:2025701:2] ET POLICY SMB2 NT Create AndX Request For an Executable File [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 192.168.0.2:2746 -> 192.168.0.3:445
Aug  3 14:27:36 192.168.0.1 snort[92683]: [1:2025701:2] ET POLICY SMB2 NT Create AndX Request For an Executable File [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 192.168.0.2:2746 -> 192.168.0.3:445
Aug  4 10:46:14 192.168.0.1 snort[92683]: [1:2025709:2] ET POLICY SMB2 NT Create AndX Request For a DLL File - Possible Lateral Movement [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 192.168.0.2:6342 -> 192.168.0.3:445
Aug  4 10:46:14 192.168.0.1 snort[92683]: [1:2025701:2] ET POLICY SMB2 NT Create AndX Request For an Executable File [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 192.168.0.2:6342 -> 192.168.0.3:445
Aug  4 10:46:14 192.168.0.1 snort[92683]: [1:2025699:2] ET POLICY SMB Executable File Transfer [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 192.168.0.2:6342 -> 192.168.0.3:445
Aug  4 10:46:15 192.168.0.1 snort[92683]: [1:2025701:2] ET POLICY SMB2 NT Create AndX Request For an Executable File [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 192.168.0.2:6342 -> 192.168.0.3:445
Aug  4 10:46:15 192.168.0.1 snort[92683]: [1:2025701:2] ET POLICY SMB2 NT Create AndX Request For an Executable File [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 192.168.0.2:6342 -> 192.168.0.3:445
Aug  4 10:46:16 192.168.0.1 snort[92683]: [1:2025701:2] ET POLICY SMB2 NT Create AndX Request For an Executable File [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 192.168.0.2:6342 -> 192.168.0.3:445
Aug  4 10:49:36 192.168.0.1 php-fpm[349]: /snort/snort_alerts.php: [Snort] Snort RELOAD CONFIG for LAN...
Aug  4 10:49:36 192.168.0.1 php-fpm[349]: /snort/snort_alerts.php: [Snort] Snort RELOAD CONFIG for LAN...
Aug  4 10:51:38 192.168.0.1 php-fpm[62611]: /snort/snort_rulesets.php: [Snort] Updating rules configuration for: LAN ...
Aug  4 10:51:40 192.168.0.1 php-fpm[62611]: /snort/snort_rulesets.php: [Snort] Enabling any flowbit-required rules for: LAN...
Aug  4 10:51:40 192.168.0.1 php-fpm[62611]: /snort/snort_rulesets.php: [Snort] Building new sid-msg.map file for LAN...
Aug  4 10:51:41 192.168.0.1 php-fpm[62611]: /snort/snort_rulesets.php: [Snort] Snort RELOAD CONFIG for LAN...
Aug  4 23:45:21 192.168.0.1 snort[92683]: [1:2025701:2] ET POLICY SMB2 NT Create AndX Request For an Executable File [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 192.168.0.2:6342 -> 192.168.0.3:445
Aug  4 23:45:22 192.168.0.1 snort[92683]: [1:2025701:2] ET POLICY SMB2 NT Create AndX Request For an Executable File [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 192.168.0.2:6342 -> 192.168.0.3:445
Aug  4 23:45:22 192.168.0.1 snort[92683]: [1:2025701:2] ET POLICY SMB2 NT Create AndX Request For an Executable File [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 192.168.0.2:6342 -> 192.168.0.3:445
Aug  4 23:45:22 192.168.0.1 snort[92683]: [1:2025701:2] ET POLICY SMB2 NT Create AndX Request For an Executable File [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 192.168.0.2:6342 -> 192.168.0.3:445
Aug  4 23:45:22 192.168.0.1 snort[92683]: [1:2025701:2] ET POLICY SMB2 NT Create AndX Request For an Executable File [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 192.168.0.2:6342 -> 192.168.0.3:445
Aug  4 23:45:22 192.168.0.1 snort[92683]: [1:2025701:2] ET POLICY SMB2 NT Create AndX Request For an Executable File [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 192.168.0.2:6342 -> 192.168.0.3:445
Aug  4 23:45:23 192.168.0.1 snort[92683]: [1:2025701:2] ET POLICY SMB2 NT Create AndX Request For an Executable File [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 192.168.0.2:6342 -> 192.168.0.3:445
```

Expected Output:

```
Jun 22 23:15:09 192.168.0.1 snort[8791]: [120:28:1] (http_inspect) INVALID CHUNK SIZE OR CHUNK SIZE FOLLOWED BY JUNK CHARACTERS [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 192.168.0.6:40932 -> 192.168.0.99:80
Jun 22 23:35:46 192.168.0.1 snort[8791]: [120:28:1] (http_inspect) INVALID CHUNK SIZE OR CHUNK SIZE FOLLOWED BY JUNK CHARACTERS [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 192.168.0.6:37647 -> 192.168.0.18:80
Jun 25 00:17:41 192.168.0.1 snort[8791]: [120:28:1] (http_inspect) INVALID CHUNK SIZE OR CHUNK SIZE FOLLOWED BY JUNK CHARACTERS [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 192.168.0.6:46210 -> 192.168.0.9:80
Jun 25 00:26:30 192.168.0.1 snort[8791]: [120:28:1] (http_inspect) INVALID CHUNK SIZE OR CHUNK SIZE FOLLOWED BY JUNK CHARACTERS [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 192.168.0.6:39421 -> 192.168.0.13:80
Aug  2 15:41:03 192.168.0.1 snort[92683]: [1:2025701:2] ET POLICY SMB2 NT Create AndX Request For an Executable File [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 192.168.0.2:51231 -> 192.168.0.3:445
Aug  3 11:00:08 192.168.0.1 snort[92683]: [1:2030215:2] ET POLICY DNS Query to .onion proxy Domain (onion . ly) [Classification: Potential Corporate Privacy Violation] [Priority: 1] {UDP} 192.168.0.2:62288 -> 192.168.0.1:53
Aug  3 11:00:08 192.168.0.1 snort[92683]: [1:2030215:2] ET POLICY DNS Query to .onion proxy Domain (onion . ly) [Classification: Potential Corporate Privacy Violation] [Priority: 1] {UDP} 192.168.0.2:62288 -> 192.168.0.1:53
Aug  3 11:00:10 192.168.0.1 snort[92683]: [1:2030216:2] ET POLICY .onion.ly Proxy domain in SNI [Classification: Potential Corporate Privacy Violation] [Priority: 1] {TCP} 192.168.0.2:3698 -> 191.168.0.18:443
Aug  3 13:50:24 192.168.0.1 snort[92683]: [1:2025701:2] ET POLICY SMB2 NT Create AndX Request For an Executable File [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 192.168.0.2:2746 -> 192.168.0.3:445
Aug  3 13:50:24 192.168.0.1 snort[92683]: [1:2025701:2] ET POLICY SMB2 NT Create AndX Request For an Executable File [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 192.168.0.2:2746 -> 192.168.0.3:445
Aug  3 13:50:25 192.168.0.1 snort[92683]: [1:2025701:2] ET POLICY SMB2 NT Create AndX Request For an Executable File [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 192.168.0.2:2746 -> 192.168.0.3:445
Aug  3 14:27:36 192.168.0.1 snort[92683]: [1:2025701:2] ET POLICY SMB2 NT Create AndX Request For an Executable File [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 192.168.0.2:2746 -> 192.168.0.3:445
Aug  4 10:46:14 192.168.0.1 snort[92683]: [1:2025709:2] ET POLICY SMB2 NT Create AndX Request For a DLL File - Possible Lateral Movement [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 192.168.0.2:6342 -> 192.168.0.3:445
Aug  4 10:46:14 192.168.0.1 snort[92683]: [1:2025701:2] ET POLICY SMB2 NT Create AndX Request For an Executable File [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 192.168.0.2:6342 -> 192.168.0.3:445
Aug  4 10:46:14 192.168.0.1 snort[92683]: [1:2025699:2] ET POLICY SMB Executable File Transfer [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 192.168.0.2:6342 -> 192.168.0.3:445
Aug  4 10:46:15 192.168.0.1 snort[92683]: [1:2025701:2] ET POLICY SMB2 NT Create AndX Request For an Executable File [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 192.168.0.2:6342 -> 192.168.0.3:445
Aug  4 10:46:15 192.168.0.1 snort[92683]: [1:2025701:2] ET POLICY SMB2 NT Create AndX Request For an Executable File [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 192.168.0.2:6342 -> 192.168.0.3:445
Aug  4 10:46:16 192.168.0.1 snort[92683]: [1:2025701:2] ET POLICY SMB2 NT Create AndX Request For an Executable File [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 192.168.0.2:6342 -> 192.168.0.3:445
Aug  4 23:45:21 192.168.0.1 snort[92683]: [1:2025701:2] ET POLICY SMB2 NT Create AndX Request For an Executable File [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 192.168.0.2:6342 -> 192.168.0.3:445
Aug  4 23:45:22 192.168.0.1 snort[92683]: [1:2025701:2] ET POLICY SMB2 NT Create AndX Request For an Executable File [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 192.168.0.2:6342 -> 192.168.0.3:445
Aug  4 23:45:22 192.168.0.1 snort[92683]: [1:2025701:2] ET POLICY SMB2 NT Create AndX Request For an Executable File [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 192.168.0.2:6342 -> 192.168.0.3:445
Aug  4 23:45:22 192.168.0.1 snort[92683]: [1:2025701:2] ET POLICY SMB2 NT Create AndX Request For an Executable File [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 192.168.0.2:6342 -> 192.168.0.3:445
Aug  4 23:45:22 192.168.0.1 snort[92683]: [1:2025701:2] ET POLICY SMB2 NT Create AndX Request For an Executable File [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 192.168.0.2:6342 -> 192.168.0.3:445
Aug  4 23:45:22 192.168.0.1 snort[92683]: [1:2025701:2] ET POLICY SMB2 NT Create AndX Request For an Executable File [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 192.168.0.2:6342 -> 192.168.0.3:445
Aug  4 23:45:23 192.168.0.1 snort[92683]: [1:2025701:2] ET POLICY SMB2 NT Create AndX Request For an Executable File [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 192.168.0.2:6342 -> 192.168.0.3:445
```

Comment: Use `-E` option in `grep` or use `"\[[0-9]*:[0-9]*:[0-9]*\]"`

Comment: what is the output you are expecting ??

Comment: see anubhava, the + is taken literal because you forgot to announce it is regex

Comment: `grep "\[[0-9]*:[0-9]*:[0-9]*\]" file` will get you expected output.

Comment: You don't need to escape the `]`, it's not treated as a regexp metachar unless preceded with an opening `[`.

Answer (score 2):

The `+` symbol is read as a literal `+` in your expression. Use the `-E` option for POSIX ERE compliance.

Also, you have a useless use of `cat`, `grep` also accepts a file as argument.

```
grep -vE '\[[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+\]' example.txt
```

Comment: In fact, it accepts one or more files as arguments.

Comment: *cat example | grep* is often used in example code when question is about grep from stdout(stdin) in real code

Answer (score 2):

Standard `grep` doesn't treat `+` as a quantifier; use `\+` instead:

```
grep -v '\[[0-9]\+:[0-9]\+:[0-9]\+\]' example.txt
```

Or specify that you want a flavor of regular expression that recognizes plain `+` as a quantifier with the `-E` option as in @Ryszard Czech's answer, or by using the command `egrep` instead of `grep`.

Just be aware of the other things that change when switching regex flavors. For example, in `grep -E` or `egrep`, you form capture groups with regular parentheses and have to use backslashes to match literal ones, the opposite of `grep` without `-E`.

Also, it's a good idea to put your `grep` patterns – and anything else you want to make it through to a command literally without any shell munging – in single quotes instead of double quotes. Most of the time it won't matter, but sometimes it does.